# I cannot figure out why my yaml.load is blowing up

Tags: python, yaml

I have this python script where I pull down some text from the librivox.org web site.  I try to save the "description" of an audiobook in both yaml and json.  They way I am attempting to do this is to generate my yaml and use python to translate that to python.  The problem I am running into is that this line ...

```
    myyaml = yaml.load(yaml_version)
```

... fails with there trace output ...

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./test-get-description.py", line 143, in <module>
    main(sys.argv[1:])
  File "./test-get-description.py", line 136, in main
    myyaml = yaml.load(yaml_version)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/yaml/__init__.py", line 71, in load
    return loader.get_single_data()
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/yaml/constructor.py", line 37, in get_single_data
    node = self.get_single_node()
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/yaml/composer.py", line 36, in get_single_node
    document = self.compose_document()
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/yaml/composer.py", line 55, in compose_document
    node = self.compose_node(None, None)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/yaml/composer.py", line 84, in compose_node
    node = self.compose_mapping_node(anchor)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/yaml/composer.py", line 127, in compose_mapping_node
    while not self.check_event(MappingEndEvent):
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/yaml/parser.py", line 98, in check_event
    self.current_event = self.state()
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/yaml/parser.py", line 439, in parse_block_mapping_key
    "expected <block end>, but found %r" % token.id, token.start_mark)
yaml.parser.ParserError: while parsing a block mapping
  in "<unicode string>", line 2, column 1:
    amazon_app_id: 'junk'
    ^
expected <block end>, but found '<scalar>'
  in "<unicode string>", line 11, column 2:
     x
     ^
```

Here is the script:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import sys, getopt
import json
import yaml
import requests
import subprocess
import re

hiera_dir               = '/home/hiera/audiobooks'

from HTMLParser import HTMLParser

class MLStripper(HTMLParser):
    def __init__(self):
        self.reset()
        self.fed = []
    def handle_data(self, d):
        self.fed.append(d)
    def get_data(self):
        return ''.join(self.fed)

def strip_tags(html):
    s = MLStripper()
    s.feed(html)
    return s.get_data()


def usage(msg):
        print msg


def write_file( data, fn ):
        print "Writing output to %s\n" % (fn)
        with open(fn, "w") as fh:
                fh.write(data)

def main(argv):
        global top
        global version
        global package
        appname                 = 'unknown'
        librivox_id             = 'unknown'
        app_image_url           = 'unknown'
        email                   = 'unknown'
        acctpasswd              = 'unknown'
        password                = 'XXXXXXX'
        try:
              opts, args = getopt.getopt(argv,"hn:l:t:v:k:p:i:e:P:",["appname", "id=","top=","version=","package=","password=","image_url=","email=","acctpasswd="])
        except getopt.GetoptError:
              print 'make_hiera_data_from_librivox_api.py -n <appname> -l <librvox id> -e <developer email> -P <developer passwd> [-t <top>] [-v <version>] [-p <password>]'
              sys.exit(2)
        for opt, arg in opts:
                if opt == '-h':
                        usage ( 'Help called' )
                        sys.exit(0)
                elif opt in ("-n", "--appname"):
                        appname = arg
                elif opt in ("-l", "--id"):
                        librivox_id = arg
                elif opt in ("-t", "--top"):
                        top = arg
                elif opt in ("-v", "--version"):
                        version = arg
                elif opt in ("-p", "--password"):
                        password = arg
                elif opt in ("-k", "--package"):
                        password = arg
                elif opt in ("-i", "--image_url"):
                        app_image_url = arg
                elif opt in ("-e", "--email"):
                        email = arg
                elif opt in ("-P", "--acctpasswd"):
                        acctpasswd = arg

        if ( appname == 'unknown' ):
                usage ("Please specify a appname")
                sys.exit (1)
        if ( librivox_id == 'unknown' ):
                usage ("Please specify a librivox api id")
                sys.exit (1)

# https://librivox.org/api/feed/audiobooks/id/9485/extended/1/format/json
        librivox_rest_url       = "https://librivox.org/api/feed/audiobooks/id/" + librivox_id + "/extended/1/format/json"
        try:
                parsed          = json.loads(requests.get(librivox_rest_url).text)
        except:
                e = sys.exc_info()[0]
                print "Error on %s Error [%s]" % ( librivox_rest_url, e )
                sys.exit(1)

        try:
                book_key        = parsed['books'].keys()[0]
        except:
                e = sys.exc_info()[0]
                print "Error on %s Error [%s]" % ( librivox_rest_url, e )
                sys.exit(1)
        apptitle        = parsed['books'][book_key]['title']
        app_zip_url     = parsed['books'][book_key]['url_zip_file']
        description     = parsed['books'][book_key]['description']
        description     = strip_tags(parsed['books'][book_key]['description'].encode('ascii', 'ignore').decode('ascii'))

        description     = re.sub("^"," ", description, flags=re.MULTILINE)
        description     = re.sub("^$"," X", description, flags=re.MULTILINE)
        description     = re.sub("^ $"," x", description, flags=re.MULTILINE)
        for d in description.split("\n"):
                print "d is [%s]\n" % (d)

        amazon_app_id   = 'junk'
        top             = 'junk'
        package         = 'junk'
        version         = 'junk'
        password        = 'junk'
        yaml_version = """---
amazon_app_id: '%s'
librivox_rest_url: '%s'
librivox_id: '%s'
top: '%s'
package: '%s'
version: '%s'
password: '%s'
description: |
 %s

""" % (
                                                        amazon_app_id
                                                ,       librivox_rest_url
                                                ,       librivox_id
                                                ,       top
                                                ,       package
                                                ,       version
                                                ,       password
                                                ,       description )
        print yaml_version
        write_file( yaml_version, hiera_dir + '/' + appname + '.yaml' );
        myyaml = yaml.load(yaml_version)
        json_version = json.dumps( yaml.load(yaml_version), sort_keys=True, indent=2)
        print json_version

        write_file( json_version, doc_root_audiobook_json + '/' + appname + '.json' );

if __name__ == "__main__":
   main(sys.argv[1:])
```

I run the script like so:

```
[red@localhost scripts]$ ./test-get-description.py -n 'junk' -l 3269
```

The ID 3269 take one to this url:

https://librivox.org/api/feed/audiobooks/id/3269/extended/1/format/json

The yaml file that I write looks like this:

```
---
amazon_app_id: 'junk'
librivox_rest_url: 'https://librivox.org/api/feed/audiobooks/id/3269/extended/1/format/json'
librivox_id: '3269'
top: 'junk'
package: 'junk'
version: 'junk'
password: 'junk'
description: |
  It is the end of the 19th century. Like thousands of others, the Rudkus family has emigrated from Lithuania to America in search of a better life. As they settle into the Packingtown neighborhood of Chicago, they find their dreams are unlikely to be realized. In fact, just the opposite is quite likely to occur. Jurgis, the main character of the novel, has brought his father Antanas, his fiance Ona, her stepmother Teta Elzbieta, Teta Elzbieta's brother Jonas and her six children, and Ona's cousin Marija Berczynskas along. The family, nave to the ways of Chicago, quickly falls prey to con men and makes a series of bad decisions that lead them into wretched poverty and terrible living conditions. All are forced to find jobs in dismal working conditions for their very survival. Jurgis, broken and discouraged, eventually finds solace in the American Socialist movement.
 x
 This novel was written during a period in American history when Trusts were formed by multiple corporations to establish monopolies that stifled competition and fixed prices. Unthinkable working conditions and unfair business practices were the norm. The Jungles author, Upton Sinclair, was an ardent Socialist of the time. Sinclair was commissioned by the Appeal To Reason, a Socialist journal of the period, to write a fictional expose on the working conditions of the immigrant laborers in the meat packing industry in Chicago. Going undercover, Sinclair spent seven weeks inside the meatpacking plants gathering details for his novel.
 x
 The Reader wishes to gratefully acknowledge the assistance, and patience, of Professor Giedrius Subacius (University of Illinois) and the folks at Lituanus for their invaluable support as I struggled with Lithuanian pronunciations. Truly, this audio book would have been far more difficult, and far less authentic, without their help.
 x
 And now, feel free to wander into The Jungle.
 x
 (Summary by Tom Weiss)
```

Comment: Why don't you use PyYaml's emitter capabilities to generate the YAML? That way, you can be sure there are no syntax errors.

Comment: I guess because I never heard of that.  Can you elaborate? Thanks.

Comment: Hmm. I don't think the emitter can deal with "block" yaml data. But I am probably wrong. Do you know how I can generate a yaml block with the python emitter?

Comment: afaik PyYaml will generate a block scalar when the content is long enough so that it seems appropriate. But generally, the possibilities to alter the representation which will be generated are limited.

Comment: Ok thanks.  But I have been looking for documentation about the emitter but I cannot find it. Can you get me pointed in the right direction? With a link :)

Comment: Well the high-level API is `yaml.dump`. For a more low-level API, you can use the [Dumper](http://pyyaml.org/wiki/PyYAMLDocumentation#Dumper) class.

Comment: You can make everything to be dumped as block style using `safe_dump(data, stream, default_flow_style=False)`, both in PyYAML and `ruamel.yaml`. If you need more fine-grained control (individual forcing of quoted scalars e.g.) you can do that with ruamel.yaml as well.

Comment: Hi @flyx I have run into to problem with the emitter approach maybe you can take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42990994/python-yaml-hiera-and-how-to-value-be-inside-double-quotes and help me out again.:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is in your literal scalar. Because you don't give [indentation explicitly the indent is determined from the first non-empty line](http://yaml.org/spec/1.2/spec.html#id2793979). In your case this is 2. Since some of the other lines have less indentation than the first line, you'll have to specify your indentation explicitly:

```
description: |1
  It is the end .....
```

Your lines don't have to be aligned.

Unless you are 100% you'll never read YAML from uncontrolled sources, you should not be using `.load()` as it is unsafe. Use `safe_load()` instead.

Comment: awesome! Didn't know you could do that!

Answer (score 1):

You have an indentantion problem with the literal block, all it's lines must maintain at least the same indentation level.

> In YAML block styles, structure is determined by indentation. In
>   general, indentation is defined as a zero or more space characters at
>   the start of a line.

So this will work:

```
description: |
  It is the end of the 19th century. Like thousands of others, the Rudkus family has emigrated from Lithuania to America in search of a better life. As they settle into the Packingtown neighborhood of Chicago, they find their dreams are unlikely to be realized. In fact, just the opposite is quite likely to occur. Jurgis, the main character of the novel, has brought his father Antanas, his fiance Ona, her stepmother Teta Elzbieta, Teta Elzbieta's brother Jonas and her six children, and Ona's cousin Marija Berczynskas along. The family, nave to the ways of Chicago, quickly falls prey to con men and makes a series of bad decisions that lead them into wretched poverty and terrible living conditions. All are forced to find jobs in dismal working conditions for their very survival. Jurgis, broken and discouraged, eventually finds solace in the American Socialist movement.
  x
  This novel was written during a period in American history when Trusts were formed by multiple corporations to establish monopolies that stifled competition and fixed prices. Unthinkable working conditions and unfair business practices were the norm. The Jungles author, Upton Sinclair, was an ardent Socialist of the time. Sinclair was commissioned by the Appeal To Reason, a Socialist journal of the period, to write a fictional expose on the working conditions of the immigrant laborers in the meat packing industry in Chicago. Going undercover, Sinclair spent seven weeks inside the meatpacking plants gathering details for his novel.
  x
  The Reader wishes to gratefully acknowledge the assistance, and patience, of Professor Giedrius Subacius (University of Illinois) and the folks at Lituanus for their invaluable support as I struggled with Lithuanian pronunciations. Truly, this audio book would have been far more difficult, and far less authentic, without their help.
  x
  And now, feel free to wander into The Jungle.
  x
  (Summary by Tom Weiss)
```

Comment: Ah yes. I see that.  I have been trying to come up with a regex that will fix that. But no luck so far. Maybe a regex that will remove back-to-back spaces?  I can't even figure that out.

Comment: Try to use this instead: `re.sub(r'^\s*(\S)',r' \1', description, flags=re.MULTILINE)`

Comment: Thanks. I tried that with the description I pull from here: https://librivox.org/api/feed/audiobooks/id/3269/extended/1/format/json but that doesn't fix it.

Comment: Can you post the description content just before `re` actions?