# How to get hiera to output the literal string '%{::fqdn}'?

Tags: yaml, hiera

I would like to know what I would need to have in my yaml file to have hiera output the literal string `%{::fqdn}` instead of outputting the value of the puppet fact `fqdn`.

Here is what I have tried.

```
# grep foo::p4 /etc/puppetlabs/code/environments/production/hieradata/bar.yaml
foo::p4: 'http://%{hiera(''p1'')}/%{::fqdn}'
```

And this is the result:

```
# hiera foo::p4 '::prefix_fact=bar' '::fqdn=thing.com' environment=production
http://test/thing.com
```

What I actually want the output to be is:

```
http://%{hiera('p1')}/%{::fqdn}
```

I guess I could do something goofy like this:

```
p1: 'test'
pa: '%{hiera'
pb: '("p1")}'
pc: '%{::fq'
pd: 'dn}'
foo::p4: "%{hiera('pa')}%{hiera('pb')}%{hiera('pc')}%{hiera('pd')}"
```

Then the output is what I want:

```
# hiera foo::p4 '::prefix=bar' '::fqdn=thing.com' environment=production
%{hiera("p1")}%{::fqdn}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [documentation](https://docs.puppet.com/hiera/3.3/variables.html#the-literal-lookup-function):

```
foo:p4: 'http://%{literal(''%'')}{hiera(''p1'')}/%{literal(''%'')}{::fqdn}'
```